# Getting error while overriding class variables in dart

Tags: flutter, dart

I have been learning dart but having some issue with the below code in which I have used default constructor to avoid taking default values inside the class as a practice but the compiler says that it is must to initialize class variables as those values can't be nullable. Is it really needed to assign class properties if my default constructor is assigning those values while initializing objects of class in the main ? Kindly help on this.

```
      class Person
      {
       String name;
       int age; 

        Person(String st_name, int age)
         {
          name = st_name;
          this.age = age;
         }
       }

   void main()
   {
    Person obj_p1 = new Person('Ralph',25);
    var obj_p2 = Person('Mark', 26);
    
    print(obj_p1.name);
    print(obj_p1.age);
    
    print(obj_p2.name);
    print(obj_p2.age);
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**EDIT**

To use this with named parameters, prefix the parameters in the constructor with `required` like so:

```dart
class Person {
  final String name;
  final int age;

  Person({required this.name, required this.age});
}
```

---

To fix this, I prefixed your variables with the `late` keyword which informs the compiler that you will be initializing this variable later (aka in the constructor).

```dart
class Person {
  late String name;
  late int age;

  Person(String st_name, int age) {
    name = st_name;
    this.age = age;
  }
}

void main() {
  Person obj_p1 = new Person('Ralph', 25);
  var obj_p2 = Person('Mark', 26);

  print(obj_p1.name);
  print(obj_p1.age);

  print(obj_p2.name);
  print(obj_p2.age);
}
```

However, in Dart, that's not the recommended way to initialize variables for a class. The correct way is as follows:

```dart
class Person {
  final String name;
  final int age;

  Person(this.name, this.age);
}
```

The above code is essentially the code in the first block. The `final` keyword just tells the compiler that this variable can't be changed once it's passed in the constructor.

Comment: I modified the code as you mentioned earlier and that was working fine. But when I am using this code with named arguments it gives an error again that class variables can't be null. So is this the correct way to use named arguments or i'm making any mistake because if I initialize any value in constructor it works fine.
 Code : 
Person({this.name, this.age});  gives error*******
Person({this.name="x", this.age=20}); works fine
*******
main object initialization for named arguments  ---
var obj_p2 = Person( name : 'Mark', age: 26);